# Lag when playing simultaneous audio clips with SoundEffect

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm working on a Windows Phone app and am having the following problem. I have a looped .Wav file for background music which can be toggled on or off. Additional sound effects (e.g. Sound1) can be played on button press. When the background music is off, the sound effects play fine. However, when the background music is on, there is a slight (but very noticeable) lag between button press and sound effect. Is there anything I can do programatically to avoid this? Per the recommendations on the MSDN website http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx, I setup a dispatcherTimer to call FrameworkDispatcher.Update every 50 ms. However, this does not seem to help too much... I have pasted some of my code below. Is there anything else I can do to get rid of this lag?

```
public partial class Modules : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    static SoundEffectInstance loopedSound = null;
    static SoundEffectInstance sound1=null;
    double pitchValue = 4.0;
    static double pitchAdjust = 0.0;

    public Modules()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Timer to simulate the XNA game loop (SoundEffect classes are from the XNA Framework)
        DispatcherTimer XnaDispatchTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        XnaDispatchTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
        XnaDispatchTimer.Tick += delegate { try { FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); } catch { } };
        XnaDispatchTimer.Start();
    }



    private void playButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (loopedSound!=null) 
            loopedSound.Dispose();
        SoundEffect sound = SoundEffect.FromStream(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"BackgroundSound.wav", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
        LoopClip(sound);

    }

    private void stopButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        loopedSound.Stop();
    }

    static protected void LoopClip(SoundEffect soundEffect)
    {
        loopedSound = soundEffect.CreateInstance();
        loopedSound.IsLooped = true;
        loopedSound.Pitch = (float) pitchAdjust;
        loopedSound.Play();
    }

    static protected void sound1Clip(SoundEffect soundEffect)
    {
        sound1 = soundEffect.CreateInstance();
        sound1.IsLooped = false;
        sound1.Play();
    }


    private void Sound1Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sound1 == null)
        {
            SoundEffect sound =    SoundEffect.FromStream(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"sound1.wav", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
            sound1Clip(sound);
        }
        if (sound1 != null)
        {

            sound1.Play();
        }


    }



}
```

}

Comment: i've long held a theory that there's a fundamental issue that makes synching video and audio an exercise in approximation.. i'll be interested to see if someone knows..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-load the SoundEffect so you don't get the delay from FromStream().  That's however not very phone-friendly.

Comment: How do you pre-load the SoundEffect? Also, why is this not phone-friendly?

Comment: To pre-load, call FromStream during initialization, and save the effect in a Dictionary or similar. However, that's gonna keep all sounds in memory, which can get expensive in a phone app.

Comment: You preload it by moving the statement to the constructor so the SoundEffect is loaded by the time you need it.  It is not phone friendly because it is a very resource constrained device.  It works better when you load resources when you need them.  Finding the right balance is a programmer's job.

Comment: @Kyte I have exact similar requirement where I want to have a common ambience / background music for entire app plus other sounds on image clicks. As per the certification document "The SoundEffect class must not be used to play a continuous background music track in an application" So did your app pass certification? In one of the sample code they use MediaElement for continuous background audio. Any suggestions?

Comment: @oms Well, I haven't actually _made_ an app, so naturally I have nothing to certify, but I wouldn't use the SoundEffect for background music either. One possibility is to use the Song & MediaPlayer classes, the latter which can be set to auto-repeat whichever Song you load onto it.